# How do emitted photons in a moving light clock keep moving sideways with the clock when photons have no mass and therefore no inertia?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, momentum, relative-motion

I have yet to read or hear a plausible explanation for how vertically emitted light waves/photons, coherent ones like from a laser, are able to keep moving horizontally with a moving light clock so that they trace out a zig-zag path when light has no mass and therefore no inertia, which is what keeps a dropped ball on a train moving horizontally with the train. Why would the light pulse keep moving sideways during the time it's in the middle area of the light clock apparatus as if it were a physical object subject to inertia? The light waves obviously wouldn't be propagating on a slant, because they weren't emitted on a slant, so the photons would have to be pushed/pulled along perpendicular to their direction of propagation. What force or property would be moving a photon sideways as it propagates vertically? Isn't it true that it's an impossibility of physics for vertically emitted massless photons to behave exactly like a physical object dropped inside a moving train?

Comment: The laserpointer you use in the train is directed vertically, every photon emitted is emitted in the same direction you hold your laser. so all the photons have just to go vertical.

Answer (score 3):

The light moves on a slant because it is emitted on a slant.

The wave propagates perpendicular to its lines of constant phase, which in a stationary laser are parallel to the aperture, say:

$$ \phi(x, z, t) = k_zz-\omega t$$

Note that:

$$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = 0 $$

Lines of constant phase are all parallel to $\hat{x}$.

Now boost in the $+x$ direction

$$ \phi(x', z', t') = k'_zz'+k'_xx' -\omega't' = kz-\omega'[\gamma(t-vx/c^2)] =  \phi(x, z, t) $$

..and so on. Basically phase is a Lorentz scalar:

$$ \phi = k^{\mu}x_{\mu} = \frac{\omega}c ct - \vec k \cdot \vec r $$

so the boost introduces a phase ramp in the $x'$-direction.

Well all know from antenna theory that phase ramps slant the beam.

Comment: Einstein died in 1955, lasers were invented in 1958, so Einstein had some excuse for believing his obviously flawed conception of the direction of travel of light, but what excuse have physicists had since 1958? Does a laser beam emitted vertically propagate diagonally if the emitter is moving horizontally? Obviously not. What is the speed of a laser beam sideways? There is none. If the light clock used a laser burst as the light pulse, would the pulse be propagating diagonally? How did it shift its direction of propagation? It didn't, simple as that, so the tick time would be the same.

Comment: Stack Exchange officially stumped, haha.

Comment: The phase argument presented is correct, and shows what it looks like in 2 different 3 + 1 version of space + time. As per usual: it's the relativity of simultaneity that causes confusion.  You can also stay firmly ensconsed in Minkowski space and transform a photon's momentum (or wave vector): $k^{\mu} = (kc/c, 0, 0, k)$ and $k'^{\mu}=\Lambda(\beta \hat x)^{\mu}_{\ \nu}k^{\nu}$ has a non-zero $k'^x$. You just have to do the Lorentz transform.

Comment: Nice clear and concise answer! +1

Answer (score 2):

Just follow your own logic in another direction and you will see that your conclusion is nonsense. Imagine the light clock is stationary, so that according to your intuition the laser is 'pointing straight up and down'. Now imagine that you coast past that stationary clock in a spaceship. Because you are moving, the straight-up-and-down path in the frame of the clock is an angled one in yours. That has nothing to do with inertia, or physical forces. Indeed, go further and forget about the light. Just 'imagine' a trajectory that is straight-up-and-down in the frame of the clock and you will find that it is an angled trajectory in your frame. If you struggle to follow what I say, let me know and I will extend my answer to spell it out with an example.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say. When you say 'make it work', make what work?

Comment: Before we get sidelined, did  you understand and agree with my answer?

Comment: I think if I was moving past a stationary light clock that I would turn my head as I moved so I could actually watch it and I would see that it's obviously going vertically and at normal speed. You suggest that as I turned my head to keep looking at it that I would see it going slower than normal just because my vehicle is moving, which I must disagree with. NOW will you address the fact that it's impossible to correct for a horizontal and diagonal beam at the same time with the same clock desyncing? Nobody has ever addressed such a scenario in SR, it's your big chance.

Comment: So, there is your mistake. Suppose you walk past me at 1 meter per second just as I flash a light vertically in my frame. After a second, the coordinates of the light in my frame are horizontal=0, vertical = 299 792 458. In your frame, the coordinates are horizontal =-1, vertical =299 792 458, so the light has travelled on an angled path in your frame.

Comment: That's what you don't understand. Given that you have failed to grasp that, I have no doubt that your supposed refutation of SR is based on a misunderstanding too.

Comment: See my comment to saidthemonkey which starts with "Let a 10 m square train car be traveling left to right". I'm interested in both of you providing an answer, we'll see if either makes sense. If you can't answer that question then there's no point even discussing the light clock because SR will have been proven flawed.

Comment: @AlienGrey have you any idea how many other people have visited PSE with so-called SR refutations over the years? Do you know how many of them ended up looking like complete idiots? 100%. You don't understand SR, and yet you think you have proven it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A laser pointer is shaped as a small cylinder, and the light is generated inside this cylinder. Suppose someone in the train points the cylinder straight up.

Now suppose someone else is standing on the ground outside as the train goes by.
And suppose the train passes from left to right.

The onlooker finds that a light wave starting at the bottom of the laser pointer moves up and also moves to the right, which it has to do in order to stay inside the cylinder which is moving to the right. Eventually this light wave gets to the top of the laser pointer. It then carries on going in the direction it was moving in already, namely up and to the right.

You get the same effect if the cylinder was shooting tennis balls upwards, or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Once emitted, light travels in a straight line. In the moving light clock thought experiment, the light is emitted (from the point of view of an observer who sees the clock under motion) in a diagonal direction (so yes, the light is emitted in a slant). It remains in this direction until it hits one of the mirrors. After reflection, the light ray again travels in a straight line.

To see that it is emitted in a slant, consider the reference frame of the moving light clock. In this frame, the light is emitted in the vertical direction and thus has velocity $(0, v)$. If the clock is moving to the right with velocity $u$ relative to you, then the velocity of the light particle in your reference frame is, disregarding relativistic corrections, given by $(u, v)$. So the light ray moves diagonally at all times in your reference frame. This is also exactly the same reason why massive objects travel in a slant (as seen from the platform) when dropped from a moving train. There is no force dragging or pulling the particle in the horizontal direction. In  the reference frame of the platform, it was already emitted with some velocity component in the horizontal direction.

You ask a very interesting question of why light travels in a straight line if it is massless and thus should carry no momentum. The answer is that light actually carries momentum, even if it is massless. The definition of momentum given in Newtonian mechanics, $\mathbf{p} = m \mathbf{v}$, is not fundamental: it is the low-velocity limit of the relativistic definition of momentum. You might have seen that Einstein's formula is $E = mc^2$. This is only valid for static bodies. For particles under movement, the formula is

\begin{equation}
 E^2 = m^2 c^4 + |\mathbf{p}|^2 c^2
\end{equation}

Light travels at the speed of light and thus Newtonian approximations do not apply: the momentum of a photon is not given by $m \mathbf{v}$. Instead, by plugging in $m = 0$ in the last equation, we correctly obtain that the photon has linear momentum of magnitude $E/c$. The fact that photons travel in straight lines can then be understood as a conservation of momentum, as happens for massive bodies.

Comment: Nothing wrong with $E=mc^2$ provided you define mass as a conserved quantity. You're using the revisionist redefinition of rest mass as mass. This question is a fine example of the confusion this causes. "If photons have no mass, why ..." is one of the commonest patterns of questions on this forum.

Comment: The apparatus does not have to tilt to emit light moving with a horizontal velocity component, because the apparatus itself already is moving horizontally. About your second comment: it is very counterintuitive, but yes, the time interval between the light hitting the two mirrors is different in the two reference frames, because the velocity of light is a fundamental constant. This also happens when a ball is dropped from a moving train: the passengers of the train will record less time for the ball to hit the ground than the passengers at the platform (again, only true in relativity).

Comment: Let a train be moving to the right with velocity $v$. A passenger on the train drops a ball to the ground. He will record a time $t^{\prime}$ between him dropping the ball and it hitting the ground. You, on the station, will record a time $t$ for this same ball to hit the ground. Special relativity tell us that $t = \gamma t^{\prime}$, where $\gamma = (1 - v^2/c^2)^{-1/2}$ is the Lorentz factor. So $t > t^{\prime}$ and you, on the platform, record a longer time. This is a relativistic effect. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation.

Comment: Note that there is no paradox here because the situation is different in both reference frames. In one of them, the ball has a horizontal velocity, and in the other it has none.

Comment: You don`t see things moving horizontally falling at the exact same time as things dropped vertically if you consider relativistic corrections. The reason is time dilation, as was explained. Please check the Wikipedia link. Newtonian intuition is not always true in relativity.

Comment: Do you think I hadn't heard of Wikipedia before you mentioned it? I'm well aware of the details of Special Relativity, I just dispute that they are valid or even logical. You, or Wikipedia, saying it's true doesn't necessarily make it true. The theory is contradicted by reality. If horizontal motion affected the time taken for vertical motion it would be seen even at common velocities, like with a thrown and dropped ball. The reality that the vertical time is identical contradicts the whole premise of the light clock thought experiment, it doesn't need to be near c velocity to prove that fact.

Comment: What can impart horizontal motion to a vertical laser beam. There is no possible answer because you can't impart motion to electromagnetic waves, because they are devoid of mass. You would think that was obvious but apparently nobody here can grasp that simple concept, which is why the light clock would not have its cycle time altered by its frame being in motion. Why did you ever even think that was possible? You would have to cite an experiment in which an emitted laser beam was pushed sideways, good luck with proving energy is subject to force.

Comment: @saidthemonkey If you flew past a light clock at high velocity would that make it's light pulse suddenly start propagating on a slant, or would it just LOOK like it was doing that because you didn't bother to turn your head and keep your eyes focused on it? That's known as perception not being reality. It can't be the pulse propagating on a slant when IT'S moving but propagating vertically when YOU are moving. Isn't it true that Einstein made a very obvious mistake and based time dilation entirely on said mistake and no physicist since then has ever recognized that obvious mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You are standing on a railroad track.  A train is moving (relative to you) along the track.  Bob, Carol, Ted and Alice are all moving parallel to the train, all at different speeds (and at speeds other than the train's speed).

Now consider your frame, the train's frame, Bob's frame, Carol's frame, Ted's frame, and Alice's frame.  If the light travels vertically in any one of those frames, it travels diagonally in all the others.

You claim that it should travel vertically in **your** frame.  What makes you so special, compared to Bob, Carol, Ted or Alice?